# bind value to input angular 4 after input loaded to DOM

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular5, ngoninit

I wrote the bind script ngAfterViewInit, still is binding to undefined,  where to call after the input loaded to DOM

HTML

```
<input type="text" *ngIf="showLastContactedDate" #dateRangeLastContacted placeholder="Choose Period" (cancelDaterangepicker)="calendarCanceled($event)" (applyDaterangepicker)="calendarApplied($event)" 
 daterangepicker [options]="options"/>
```

TS

```
export class FilterContactsDialogComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('dateRangeLastContacted') dateRangeLastContacted;

    ngOnInit() {}

    ngAfterViewInit(){


    response = //calling a service method
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.dateRangeLastContacted.nativeElement.value = response.someValue;
        },0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, what you are doing is right, maybe the directive `daterangepicker` prevents the `input` to accept the value.

Comment: and applyDaterangepicker miss (